# Add another layer of validation for sequencing data

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am creating a matchmaking function where 2 players with the same weight will be paired.

It is currently working now based on the same weight. Now, my target is, to add a sequence per match. For example.

*If *player 1* is in 1st match, then player 1's next match should be on the 4th or 6th match. Every match of the player there should be a minimum of 3 and Maximum of 6 gaps before that specific player can be matched again.

I have provided my current output and my target output below.

```js
    const source = [
        {
            entryID: 1,
            entryName: "player1",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],

        }, 
        {
            entryID: 2,
            entryName: "player1",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],

        },
        {
            entryID: 3,
            entryName: "player2",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 4,
            entryName: "player3",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 5,
            entryName: "player4",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 6,
            entryName: "player5",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 7,
            entryName: "player6",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 8,
            entryName: "player7",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],

        },
        {
            entryID: 9,
            entryName: "player8",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 10,
            entryName: "player9",
            weight: 1900,
           class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 11,
           entryName: "player10",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 12,
           entryName: "player11",
            weight: 1900,
              class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 13,
           entryName: "player12",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],
        },
        {
            entryID: 14,
           entryName: "player1",
            weight: 1900,
            class:[],
        },

    ];

console.log(combine(source))

function combine(data = [], different = 0, maxGroupSize = 2) {
    const groups = [], related = [], sortedData = [...data].sort((a, b) => a.weight - b.weight),
        alreadyInRela = (setX, eName) => {
            let list = [...setX, eName]
            return related.some(rela => list.every(l => rela.has(l)))
        };
    
    sortedData.forEach((el, indx) => {
        let place = groups.findIndex( // find a place in a group forEach element, use indx as track
            g => g.names.size < maxGroupSize              // is the group incomplete ?
                && !g.names.has(el.entryName)             // is entryName not in the group list (names Set) ?
                && (el.weight - g.weight) <= different
                && !alreadyInRela(g.names, el.entryName) // is (entryName + group list) does not already used ?
                && el.class.every(c => !g.usedClasses.has(c)) // check class
        )

        if (place < 0) { // not found -> create new group
            let names = new Set().add(el.entryName)                      // create new group
            groups.push({ names, indxs: [indx], weight: el.weight, usedClasses: new Set(el.class) })  // group constitutive info 
            related.push(names)                                      // keep track of group list
        } else { // find a place in a group
            groups[place].names.add(el.entryName)  // related list is also updated
            el.class.forEach(c => groups[place].usedClasses.add(c)) // add classes
            groups[place].indxs.push(indx)        // add indx to retreive element in sortedData 
        }
    });

    return groups.reduce((r, g, i) => { // build result
        if (g.indxs.length > 1) {
            let key = `${i}_` + g.indxs.map(x => sortedData[x].weight).join('_')
            r[key] = []
            g.indxs.forEach(x => r[key].push(sortedData[x]))
        }
        return r
    }, {})
}
```

Current result:

```
{
  0_1900_1900: [{ // 1st match
  class: [],
  entryID: 1,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 3,
  entryName: "player2",
  weight: 1900
}],
  1_1900_1900: [{ // 2nd match (As we can see here, player 1 has been matched again. There should be 3-6 matches before this player can be matched again)
  class: [],
  entryID: 2,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 4,
  entryName: "player3",
  weight: 1900
}],
  2_1900_1900: [{ // 3rd match
  class: [],
  entryID: 5,
  entryName: "player4",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 6,
  entryName: "player5",
  weight: 1900
}],
  3_1900_1900: [{ // 4th match
  class: [],
  entryID: 7,
  entryName: "player6",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 8,
  entryName: "player7",
  weight: 1900
}],
  4_1900_1900: [{ // 5th match
  class: [],
  entryID: 9,
  entryName: "player8",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 10,
  entryName: "player9",
  weight: 1900
}],
  5_1900_1900: [{ // 6th match
  class: [],
  entryID: 11,
  entryName: "player10",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 12,
  entryName: "player11",
  weight: 1900
}],
  6_1900_1900: [{ // 7th match
  class: [],
  entryID: 13,
  entryName: "player12",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 14,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}]
}
```

Target result:

```
{
  0_1900_1900: [{// 1st match
  class: [],
  entryID: 1,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 3,
  entryName: "player2",
  weight: 1900
}],
  1_1900_1900: [{ //2nd match
  class: [],
  entryID: 4,
  entryName: "player3",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 5,
  entryName: "player4",
  weight: 1900
}],
  2_1900_1900: [{ //3rd match
  class: [],
  entryID: 6,
  entryName: "player5",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 7,
  entryName: "player6",
  weight: 1900
}],
  3_1900_1900: [{ //4th match (As we can see here, there are 2 matches before player 1 got matched again. This is my target output)
  class: [],
  entryID: 2,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 8,
  entryName: "player7",
  weight: 1900
}],
  4_1900_1900: [{ //5th match
  class: [],
  entryID: 9,
  entryName: "player8",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 10,
  entryName: "player9",
  weight: 1900
}],
  5_1900_1900: [{ //6th match
  class: [],
  entryID: 11,
  entryName: "player10",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 12,
  entryName: "player11",
  weight: 1900
}],
  6_1900_1900: [{ //7th match
  class: [],
  entryID: 14,
  entryName: "player1",
  weight: 1900
}, {
  class: [],
  entryID: 13,
  entryName: "player12",
  weight: 1900
}]
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: how do you want to handle when the constraint cannot be achieved? e.g. you have 3 players with the same weight. obviously the third cannot play with anybody

Comment: Hello. I am not showing it to the result anymore if that third player cannot play with anybody. I have provided a jfiddle for your reference. Additionally, i added also 1 player to show the result of what will happen if that player cannot play with anybody. 

https://jsfiddle.net/aqt687p5/2/

So basically, I am only showing the players with matches on the result (Console.log)

Thank you.

Comment: Your current and target result sets are not a valid format. Are they supposed to JSON, Javascript object or a custom string dressed up to look like JSON / JS object?

Comment: Hi, in provided json-array at `entryID: 1` the player is `player1` and for `entryID: 2` also have `player1` so how do uniquely identify them ? Also, can there be same name players ?

Comment: Hello @Swati. Yes, there can be the name players. And if there are same name, The function i have provided does not match/join it. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All variables that will be used in this solution:

- `currentPlayer` --> current player, either as `home` or `away`. For example:

```json
{
  "entryID": 1,
  "entryName": "player1",
  "weight": 1900,
  "class": []
}
```

- `match`     --> Represents an array of players in a particular match ([`home`,`away`]). For example:

```json
[
  {
    "entryID": 1,
    "entryName": "player1",
    "weight": 1900,
    "class": []
  },
  {
    "entryID": 3,
    "entryName": "player2",
    "weight": 1900,
    "class": []
  }
]
```

- `data`   --> Array of players which is the initial data are given (`source`).
- `counter`   --> Counter of each `match`.
- `matchId`   --> `counter`_`home.weight`_`away.weight`. For example `"0_1900_1900"`
- `matches`   --> All matches which each key is `matchId`. For example:

```json
{
  "0_1900_1900": [
    {
      "entryID": 1,
      "entryName": "player1",
      "weight": 1900,
      "class": []
    },
    {
      "entryID": 3,
      "entryName": "player2",
      "weight": 1900,
      "class": []
    }
  ],
  "1_1900_1900": [
    {
      "entryID": 4,
      "entryName": "player3",
      "weight": 1900,
      "class": []
    },
    {
      "entryID": 5,
      "entryName": "player4",
      "weight": 1900,
      "class": []
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Step-by-step solution:

1. Loop through each `data`
2. Check if the current player is the host.

   - If yes, add it to the `match` array and remove this player from `data`.
   - But if not, check if `home.entryName` equals `away.entryName`.

     - If yes, add it to the `match` array and remove this player from the data.
     - But if not, move this player in order after the next 5 players.
3. If the loop is on the `home` iteration, fill `matchId` with `counter_home.weight`, otherwise concat `matchId` with `_away.weight`.
4. Add new properties for `matches` with the key is `matchId` and the value is `match`.

*Hope it will help.*

```js
const source = [
    {
        entryID: 1,
        entryName: "player1",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    }, 
    {
        entryID: 2,
        entryName: "player1",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 3,
        entryName: "player2",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 4,
        entryName: "player3",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 5,
        entryName: "player4",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 6,
        entryName: "player5",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 7,
        entryName: "player6",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 8,
        entryName: "player7",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 9,
        entryName: "player8",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 10,
        entryName: "player9",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 11,
        entryName: "player10",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 12,
        entryName: "player11",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 13,
        entryName: "player12",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
    {
        entryID: 14,
        entryName: "player1",
        weight: 1900,
        class:[],
    },
];

console.log(combine(source));

function combine(data) {
  let matches = {};
  let match = [];
  let matchId = '';
  let matchCounter = 0;
  let home, away;
  let currentPlayer;
  
  while(data.length) { // Step 1
    currentPlayer = data[0];
    if(match.length) { // Step 2
      away = currentPlayer;
      if(home.entryName !== away.entryName) {
        match.push(currentPlayer);
        data.shift();
        matchId += `_${currentPlayer.weight}`;
        matches[matchId] = match; // Step 4
        match = []; matchId = ''; matchCounter++;
      } else {
        arraymove(data, 0, 5);
      }
    } else {
      match.push(currentPlayer);
      home = currentPlayer;
      data.shift();
      matchId = `${matchCounter}_${currentPlayer.weight}`; // Step 3
    }
  }
  return matches;
}

function arraymove(arr, fromIndex, toIndex) {
  let element = arr[fromIndex];
  arr.splice(fromIndex, 1);
  arr.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you, i'll study about this. I appreciate your help. :D

Comment: Hello, i have tried your codes and it is working. My question is, is there a way where i can combine your codes to mine? I'm a little bit confused. x.x Thank you 

I'm sorry, i'm just a beginner. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure can combine that code to yours because too complex. My advice is just replace `combine`  function.